# How to set properties for AMQ message

Tags: stomp, amq

I am sending XML message to AMQ queue. XML has header section. I need to set child nodes of header as properties of AMQ message. I am using NodeJS stompit package.

Currently message shows only one property which is JMSXDeliveryCount.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [stompit documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stompit) has an example where the `destination` and `content-type` headers are set when using the [`client.send`](http://gdaws.github.io/node-stomp/api/client/#clientsendheaders-options) method. You can add whatever other headers you want there.